# Finding nearest values in two vectors

Tags: algorithm, julia

Let's say I've got two sorted vectors of floating point numbers - let's call them *A* and *B*. Is there a clever way of selecting an element of *A* and an element of *B* such that those elements are nearest in value of all the pairs? Right now I'm brute forcing it with two loops, but it seems like there ought to be a better way.

Comment: Two sorted arrays [can be merged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation_using_lists) into a single sorted array in O(N) time. Then, if you keep track of which element comes from which array, you can loop over the merged array, looking for two neighboring elements coming from different arrays, with the minimum difference. That's O(N) as well.

Comment: and you do not need to materialize this merged structure; it is enough to iterate `A` and `B` e.g. using `iterate`. This will produce you the result in a single pass.

Comment: This looks like a promising line of attack - I was a bit fixated on the idea of enumerating the pairs.

Comment: One-liner for when speed isn't critical (and `A` and `B` need not be sorted): `iA,iB = argmin(abs.(A .- B')).I`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the demo :

```
julia> X=sort(rand(6)) # data example X
6-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.03229732486724901
 0.14661947289585864
 0.28060083090585386
 0.35640311556807047
 0.8995421870143288
 0.9063824527540892

julia> Y=sort(rand(5))  # data example Y (note: X and Y sizes can be different)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.40423308422286974
 0.7126138483715454
 0.8721509236032997
 0.9193793976271042
 0.9827581490910492

julia> minimum( (abs(xi-yi) for xi in X, yi in Y) ) # a short, but O(N^2) approach
0.012996944873014948

julia> (d,i,j)=find_min_dist(X,Y) # <- the proposed solution (see code below)
(0.012996944873014948, 6, 4)

julia> abs(X[i]-Y[j]) # <- check that the 2 methods give the same result
0.012996944873014948
```

Here is the complete code : this is not that short, sorry. However observe that there is only one pass, the complexity is O(N)

```
function find_min_dist(X::AbstractVector{T}, Y::AbstractVector{T}) where {T<:AbstractFloat}
    @assert !isempty(X) && !isempty(Y)

    if Y[1]<X[1]
        (d,j,i) = find_min_dist(Y,X)
        return (d,i,j)
    end
    
    @assert issorted(X) && issorted(Y)
    
    X_n = length(X)
    Y_n = length(Y)

    min_dist = typemax(T)
    min_dist_X_i = 0
    min_dist_Y_j = 0
    
    i = 1
    j = 1

    @inbounds while i ≤ X_n
        # Find first j, such that Y[j] ≥ X[i]
        # and check dist(X[i],Y[j-1]) && dist(X[i],Y[j])
        #
        if (j ≤ Y_n) && (Y[j]<X[i])
            j+=1
        else
            if j > 1, 
               min_dist_candidate = abs(X[i]-Y[j-1])
               if min_dist > min_dist_candidate 
                   min_dist = min_dist_candidate
                   min_dist_X_i = i
                   min_dist_Y_j = j-1
               end
            end

            if j ≤ Y_n
               min_dist_candidate = abs(X[i]-Y[j])
               if min_dist > min_dist_candidate 
                   min_dist = min_dist_candidate
                   min_dist_X_i = i
                   min_dist_Y_j = j
               end
            end

            i+=1
        end
    end
    
    (min_dist,min_dist_X_i,min_dist_Y_j)
end
```

Here are some explanations :

The idea is to loop once over `X` and `Y` and find the first `j` such that `Y[j] ≥ X[i]`. In order to do not miss the first `Y[1]` we permute `X` and `Y` if necessary. As soon as `Y[j] ≥ X[i]`, we check `dist(X[i],Y[j-1])` and `dist(X[i],Y[j])`. If a better `min_dist` is found, we record it with the `i,j` indices defining the best pair.

---

**update**: benchmark for `length(X)=100` & `length(Y)=200`

With all pairs comparison :

```
julia> @benchmark minimum( (abs(xi-yi) for xi in $X, yi in $Y) )
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  36.840 μs … 197.413 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     37.811 μs               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   41.021 μs ±   9.457 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  ▇█ ▆  ▄  ▃          ▁▁▁    ▁▁▁▁                              ▂
  ██▄█▅▅██▃█▃▃▁▁▄▃▄▄█████████████████▇▇▆▇▇▆▅▇▆▅▆▅▆▅▅▅▅▆▅▅▅▆▆▆▅ █
  36.8 μs       Histogram: log(frequency) by time      81.7 μs <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

With `find_min_dist` :

```
julia> @benchmark find_min_dist($X,$Y)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 181 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  583.718 ns …   2.140 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     598.771 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   655.339 ns ± 134.850 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █▇▄  ▂▁▁▂▂▂▃▃▃▁▁   ▁▁ ▁                                       ▁
  ███▇█████████████▇██████▆▆▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▆▇▆▆▆▇▆▆▆▆▅▆▅▆▅▅▆▅▅▄▅▄▃▄▄ █
  584 ns        Histogram: log(frequency) by time       1.26 μs <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

The proposed solution is 60 times faster, and you can gain a little bit more by removing the `@assert issorted`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another version, which has shorter/cleaner code and is also (on my benchmarks) slightly quicker:

```
function safe_min_dist(L1, L2)
    @assert !isempty(L1) && !isempty(L2)
    @assert issorted(L1) && issorted(L2)
    return unsafe_min_dist(L1, L2)
end

function unsafe_min_dist(L1, L2)
    swapped = L1[1] > L2[1]
    LL, HL = swapped ? (L2, L1) : (L1, L2)
    LLlen, HLlen = length(LL), length(HL)

    li, hi = 1, 1
    curmin = HL[1]-LL[1]
    curli, curhi, curswapped = li, hi, swapped

    @inbounds while true
        li += 1
        if li > LLlen || LL[li] > HL[hi]
            if HL[hi]-LL[li-1] < curmin
                curmin = HL[hi] - LL[li-1]
                curli, curhi, curswapped = li-1, hi, swapped
                curmin == 0 && break
            end
            li > LLlen && break 
            LL, HL, LLlen, HLlen = HL, LL, HLlen, LLlen
            li, hi, swapped = hi, li, !swapped
        end
    end
    return curswapped ? (curmin, curhi, curli) : (curmin, curli, curhi)
end
```

After defining these functions and `find_min_dist` from Picaud's answer and its `unsafe_` version. We can run a benchmark as follows:

```
using BenchmarkTools
using Random
Random.seed!(0x1234)

X = sort(rand(100))
Y = sort(rand(200))
```

```
julia> @btime find_min_dist($X, $Y)
  945.846 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
(1.0869188864059964e-5, 37, 78)

julia> @btime unsafe_find_min_dist($X, $Y)
  590.511 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
(1.0869188864059964e-5, 37, 78)

julia> @btime safe_min_dist($X, $Y)
  842.310 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
(1.0869188864059964e-5, 37, 78)

julia> @btime unsafe_min_dist($X, $Y)
  458.737 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
(1.0869188864059964e-5, 37, 78)
```